# getting an error putting digits from a file into an array (Java)

Tags: java

I want to take the first 15 digits from the following and put them in an array. The issue is it inputs all the digits up until "344". This digit appears as only "34". I"m assuming this is because the count is counting invalid inputs like "xxx" as digits. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

```
0
4
23
566
34
xxx
45
555
11
34
35
45
xxx
65

55
98
344
54
```

This is my code (3 sections one adds the file one plays the game and one prints the results):

```
public class JumpIt {

    // Constants
    private int count = 0;
    private final int MAX_SIZE = 15;
    public int[] arr = new int[MAX_SIZE];

    public JumpIt(String theName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        int i=0;
        while(scanner.hasNext() && count < 15) {   //only need first 15 
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
                count+= 1;
            }
            else {
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }

    int n = 0;
    public int play() throws BadInputException{             //gets size
        if(arr[0]!= 0) {
            throw new BadInputException(); 
        }
        return play(arr,0,count-1);
    }

    private static int play(int arr[],int first, int last) { 
        if(first > (last)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if ((first + 1)>last){
            return arr[first];
        }
        else {
            if (arr[first] < arr[first + 1]) {
                return arr[first] + play(arr,first+2,last);
            }
            else {
                return arr[first+1] + play(arr,first+2,last);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printGame() {
        if(count > 10) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
            n = count - 10;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        //if(count > 15) {
        //  System.out.println("The file has more than 15 integers");
        //  System.out.println("Only the first 15 integers are considered");
        //}
        else {
            n = count; 
            for(int i = 0; i < count;i++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The file has "); 
        System.out.print(count);
        System.out.println(" " + "integers.");
        }
}
```

and this is my main:

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    JumpIt game4 = new JumpIt("file.txt");
    game4.printGame();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("play game");
    try {
            System.out.println("the cost is " + game4.play());
            System.out.println("");
    } catch (BadInputException e){
            System.out.println("bad input: the first int must be 0");
    }
```

Comment: You did not initialize `count`

Comment: A separate function reads the file so my count is a global variable that I included outside of the function.

Comment: This is not complete code. I assume `count` has been initialized somewhere else? You should just be able to use `i` instead of `count`.

Comment: ya it isn't the count that's the issue I initialized it outside of this

Comment: Can you check `count` at the end to see if it exit the loop because of `count < 15` or `scanner.hasNext()`?

Comment: I tried printing out the count every time it incremented and it reaches 15 then stops the loop so I'm assuming the count is stopping it. There's a number after 344 so I'm assuming it isn't the hasNext() that is triggering it.

Comment: I just ran the code and it works fine for me. Reads all numbers till 344 and then quits cause `count > 15`. Would need to see more code around this to see what's going on. How big is `arr`? Does it throw any exceptions that you might be silently ignoring?

Comment: did it completely print out 344 for you? For some reason mines clipped and only prints 34

Comment: Before the loop `count` must be set to 0, and afterwards `scanner` closed, but otherwise the code is okay. Maybe you do not see all three digits of the last 344.

Comment: that's so odd, I set it to 0 and I'm sure it's registering as 34 because im using it for computation afterwards and it is computing as if I inputted 34.

Comment: @itachi323232 Yes. It prints complete 344. In your example you are not printing anything so check the array to see if it has the values. Add some more code in your question because this part seems to be working fine so the issue might be outside this code.

Comment: I've updated the post to include all my code

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. With small cleanup:

```
int[] arr = new int[15];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
int i = 0;
while (scanner.hasNext() && i < 15) {
  if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    arr[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
  } else {
    scanner.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Creates array with following elements [0, 4, 23, 566, 34, 45, 555, 11, 34, 35, 45, 65, 55, 98, 344].

Could it be that `count` variable in your code is greater than 0 before entering the loop? You didn't initialise it in your code snippet.

Comment: I tried this code but it is saying there are no digits in the file when I run the code

Comment: I also changed the i in the while loop to count to see what happens and when I run it, it says array out of bounds.

Comment: My code doesn't say anything it only reads an array. To see what's inside `arr` array you can `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));`. It seems you are embedding my code in some bigger method.

Comment: ya I think I'm not providing enough code so I added all my code into the post it should be a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that your program does not read the first 15 numbers into the array correctly.  In fact it does (I have verified by testing).

The reason you thought that the array wasn't being populated properly is because you saw the number 34 at the end of the printout of the array.  The last number is 344, however this logic causes the deception (you print the first 10, then start back at the beginning of the array):

```
public void printGame() {
    if(count > 10) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        n = count - 10;   // Here you are restarting back at index=0
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    ....
```

The number 34 is appearing because it is 5th element (which is 15-10).  It is unfortunate that 34 resembles 344.